# Why doesn’t adding a function to `Date` work like adding it to `Date.protoype` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

### The Original Question

I realized I am not 100% sure why this behaves the way it does, so I figured it would make a good SO question.

Observe:

```
Date.bar = function() { return 'called bar'; }
Date.prototype.foo = function() { return 'called foo'; }
```

Then in your console, note these two lines work:

```
Date.bar(); // 'called bar'
(new Date).foo() // 'called foo'
```

But these two blow up and complain about `undefined` not being a function:

```
Date.foo();
(new Date).bar();
```

In theory, shouldn't adding a method to Date's prototype make it available when called off Date? What is actually going on here?

---

### What I got out of your answers and from playing around in the console

Basically, `Date` (that is, `window.Date`) is *not a date object*. It’s a function, and it wasn’t constructed from `Date.prototype`. (Also, date objects do not have the `prototype` property defined, though of course they still have a prototype chain.) Check it out:

```
typeof Date; // function
typeof (new Date); // object
Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Date); // true
Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Date); // false
(new Date).prototype; // undefined
```

Realizing that `Date` is not a date object or the prototype for date objects makes this all make a lot more sense to me. Thanks, everyone.

Also, note that `Date.prototype` and `Date.__proto__` are different! The former is used when `Date` is run as a function, when creating new date objects. The latter is related to the normal prototype chain (and is `Date`’s prototype).

Comment: Adding a property to an object, like Date, doesn't not mean that instances of Date will inherit it. Basic prototype inheritance; instances of the constructor inherit properties of the constructor's prototype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `foo` to `Date.prototype` affects all objects created from invoking Date as a **constructor**.  That's why `foo` is visible when you say `(new Date()).foo()` but not `Date.foo()`—the latter does not invoke Date as a *constructor*.

Remember, when you say `new Date()` you get an object that's based on Date's `prototype`.  You added `foo` to the prototype, so you'll get `foo` on objects created from `new Date()`

Adding something directly to `Date` simply adds it to the `Date` function.  That's why `Date.bar()` works, but not `(new Date()).bar()`.  `bar` is not on the prototype, and therefore not visible to objects created from invoking Date as a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

But you're not actually adding `foo` to "Date's prototype", you're adding it to `Date.prototype`, which is the prototype of objects constructed by using `Date` as a constructor-function.

Technically speaking, since `Date` is a function, you can add `foo` to `Date`'s own prototype by writing `Function.prototype.foo = function() { return 'called foo'; }`; but obviously that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`Date.prototype.foo = ...` makes `foo` visible to `Date` instances via the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype).  This means you only see it in objects where you called `Date` as a constructor – `new Date();`

`Date.bar = ...` sets the `bar` property of the `Date` object, which happens to be a function (remember that all functions are objects in JavaScript).  That object has nothing to do with the `Date` instance objects you get by calling `Date` as a constructor function.

Comment: Basically, `Date` is an object like anything else, but `.prototype` is special (it's used to make instances)? I never fully understood this either.

Comment: @nkorth: Yes, `Date` is an object like anything else (see updates to answer).  The `prototype` is special in that it is basically referenced by each object created by a constructor function.  So if you have 10,000 objects, there's still only one copy of the function in memory, stored in the `prototype`.  If, however, you had a constructor function like `function Foo() { this.bar = function() { ... }}`, then there'd be a separate copy of `bar` in memory for each object created with `new Foo()`.